# How to encode SSH keys into base64 string without newlines

Tags: linux, ssh

What if you want to put your ssh private or public key into environment variable and access it on a CI system?

A key looks like this, so how can you convert it in a base64 string without newlines?

```
-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAABG5vbmUAAAAEbm9uZQAAAAAAAAABAAAAMwAAAAtzc2gtZW
QyNTUxOQAAACAICS0Scec9oD2raCs5HoZyQuZCPXJAVZvIJ+OooR0faAAAAJBsx4YgbMeG
IAAAAAtzc2gtZWQyNTUxOQAAACAICS0Scec9oD2raCs5HoZyQuZCPXJAVZvIJ+OooR0faA
AAAEDd1JmV4ligped6DH18jnlyEriUfNve+80vexKOOZjUwQgJLRJx5z2gPatoKzkehnJC
5kI9ckBVm8gn46ihHR9oAAAABmF3c2JvdAECAwQFBgc=
-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First generate your keys or you can use any existing keys whether it's RSA or ED25519

```bash
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "coo@abc.com"
```

Encode it into base64

```bash
cat id_ed25519 | base64 | tr -d \\n
```

Or

```bash
cat <filename> | base64 -w 0
```

suggested by @GPM

Now you can copy paste the output anywhere you want, this should give you a string with 0 newlines.

To verify

```
echo your_encoded_string | base64 --decode
```

You should see the same key as you had in your file.

Answer (score 2):

A quickest way is simply:

```
cat <filename> | base64 -w 0
```